# ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection is not queryable

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to programming, and I'm making a new project in visual studio 2017rc. There I want to make the use of a list box. I want to select the items in list box and make some actions.

So I wrote the following code:

```
Dim SelectedItems = (From i In ListBox1.SelectedItems).ToList

        For Each selecteditem In SelectedItems
            Peca = selecteditem
            Call CATIA_Windows_app.Save()
        Next
```

[But this is returning an error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjxIC.png)

I had used this code in other application and it works.

Have I forgot something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need an object that implements `IEnumerable(Of T)` for a LINQ query and that type only implements `IEnumerable`.  The way to get the former from the latter is to call the `Cast` method.  For instance, if your `ListBox` contains `String` objects you can do this:

```
From item In myListBox.SelectedItems.Cast(Of String)()
```